# queryTxt ETIMEOUT devconnector-fmgld.mongodb.net

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I have faced the same below problem which faced by earlier by some of the users.

I have noticed some of the users connect after some time but does not conclude the fix or error. It seems like I am stuck between this. Can you please help me to get rid of this.

Following thing that helps you to debug.

1. I have whitelisted my IP 0.0.0.0/0 which mean I can access from any IP.
2. Before, I was able to save in the MongoDB cluster.

Thank you for quick help.

````
queryTxt ETIMEOUT devconnector-fmgld.mongodb.net
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...```
````

Comment: Your dns resolution appears to be broken. You can use the non-SRV URI to work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved. It occurs due to poor internet connection. As it seems a trivial solution but more important for new learner like me to understand such kind of issues.